# What is the best way to get my avi files into flv format?

Tags: flv

I need to embed videos on a client's website and they have given the following guidelines:

- must be viewable as flash (FLV format)
- if hosted by outside company (e.g. Youtube) the video can not link back to the outside company's website
- if hosted by outside company (e.g. Youtube) the video can not have any advertisements of the outside company

I guess what I'm looking for is an AVI-to-FLV converter?

Answer (score 2):

Your client's requirements preclude using YouTube. You're probably better off hosting them on the client's site.

Flash will import your AVI movies and convert them to FLV. You can find the video import tool under File -> Import -> Import Video.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Riva VX](http://rivavx.com/index.php?encoder) on windows or [ffmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) on Mac.

Comment: Or mencoder or ffmpeg on Linux (or any of those platforms really).

Answer (score 2):

The "best" way? FFmpeg is the answer to that, its cross platform and you can easily script it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec flv output.flv
```

If you want a tool to do it (requires a human), I suggest Miro http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

Comment: +1 as I don't see any reason to use anything different. Most GUI apps are unable to propose the complete set of options and filtering that a FFMpeg command line supports. Of course there is a steeper learning curve, but it is very much worth it. I have been teaching ffmpeg usage to everyone involved with video encoding in my company :)

Answer (score 1):

[Super©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) converts anything to anything .. couldnt live without it. Got a whacked out UI but I'm willing to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/) from [Miksoft](http://www.miksoft.net/) is the best. it allows you to do batch conversion of files and also allows you to set the output quality. It is also FREE.

Comment: Mobile Media Converts add a little background noise to my flv. I recommend Riva